# Convert UTC to User-Defined Time Zone with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, activesupport

I'm needing to convert a UTC time to the equivalent time in the user's time zone as part of a Rake task. What I want to do is change a UTC timestamp for midnight and re-create the timestamp to be midnight in the time zone of the user.

#### Example

Convert a UTC time

```
Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

to Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) when observing daylight saving time (spring/summer)

```
Wed, 01 Mar 2017 04:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
time = "Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00"
time.in_time_zone(zone)
=> Tue, 28 Feb 2017 19:00:00.000000000 EST -05:00
```

The above will still save as `Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00` in the database, as Rails will convert all timestamps back to UTC. However, I'm needing to get `Wed, 01 Mar 2017 04:00:00 UTC +00:00` as that is the *true* beginning of the day in the user's time zone.

Comment: _"that is the true beginning of the day in the user's time zone"_ – not quite. March 1st is still EST (UTC−05:00). Daylight saving time EDT (UTC−04:00) starts on March 12th 2017.

Comment: @Stefan, thanks for pointing that out. This is a mistake on my part and I will update the examples above. The point still stands, where I am looking for the true beginning of the day. There looks to be some great solutions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse a string relative to a timezone via [`ActiveSupport::TimeZone#parse`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse). Just make sure to omit any time zone specifiers like "UTC +00:00":

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")

time = zone.parse("Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00")
#=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00.000000000 EST -05:00

time.utc
#=> 2017-03-01 05:00:00 UTC
```

The last call to `utc` is just for illustration purposes, Rails will perform this conversion automatically when saving `time` to the database.

With numeric input:

```
time = zone.local(2017, 3, 1)
#=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00.000000000 EST -05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to initialize the time to a specific time in a specific timezone, then you need to initialize the time with the correct EST or EDT zone identifier (`EST -05:00` or `EDT -04:00`).

```
time = "Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 EST -05:00"
time.in_time_zone('UTC')
#=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 05:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00

time = "Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 EDT -04:00"
time.in_time_zone('UTC')
#=> Wed, 01 Mar 2017 04:00:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
utc_time = "Wed, 01 Mar 2017 00:00:00 UTC +00:00"
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
usr_time = utc_time.in_time_zone(zone)
midnight_time = usr_time.beginning_of_day
utc_midnight_time = midnight_time.utc
```

Now, you can save utc_midnight_time in the database.

If you also want to create a timestamp and suppose you have a Scheduler
model. Then you can do this,
Scheduler.create(timestamp: utc_midnight_time)
and save it.